# rails 2.3.15. Can't change session expiry date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, passenger

I'm trying to set session expiry date dynamically in Rails application. It works fine on my local (run under WEBrick) but doesn't work on production (using Apache and Passenger 3.0.19)

The version of ruby I'm using is 1.8.7 and Rails version is 2.3.15.

session is configured like this by default:

```
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => '_my_session',
  :secret      => 'some_key'
}

ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store
```

I'm trying to add "remember me" functionality to the website, so when user ticks "remember me", expiration date for the cookie should be set to 2 weeks:

```
if params[:remember_me]
    ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 2.weeks
else
  ActionController::Base.session_options.delete :expire_after
end
```

This works fine when i test the code locally: when i send the first request to the website (opening login in page) it creates a cookie with default expiration date (so it expires when browser gets closed), then i tick "remember me" and press "log in". My code then gets executed setting the expiry date to 2 weeks and i get redirected to the main page of the website. I can see "set-cookie" in the response, so it updates my cookie to expire after 2 weeks.

But when I deploy the code to production that uses passenger it doesn't work: I get the cookie with default expiry date created when I open the log in page, but when i log in with "remember me" ticked in, the server logs me in and redirects to main page but doesn't send me the new cookie with expiry date set up.

When I modify the default configuration on production to expire after 2 weeks (rather than changing it dynamically), so "remember me" is basically on for all users, it creates the cookie with correct expiry date from the very beginning. But when I change the settings dynamically it seems to ignore them and they are not reflected in cookies. I added some logs in production and I can clearly see that ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] really does get updated, but the new cookie is never sent to the client.
I tried googling and following a lot of advices, but none of them works for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
I found a useful link on stackoverflow that helped me to resolve the problem:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base
the last comment on that page helped me to solve the problem
i changed

```
if params[:remember_me]
    ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 2.weeks
else
   ActionController::Base.session_options.delete :expire_after
end
```

into

```
if params[:remember_me]
    request.session_options[:expire_after] = 2.weeks
else
    request.session_options[:expire_after] = nil
end
```

now the cookie gets updated.